# Can the flurry HTML5 SDK be used to track events in phonegap apps?

Tags: html, cordova, flurry

I have built an app using phonegap and have deployed on iOS and Android right now. I have come across flurry and it seems like an awesome product for analytics. However, I am confused about whether we can use the HTML5 SDK to directly log events from my javascript code, or should I create some plugins and use the native Android/iOS SDK to log events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it directly from your javascript code and this will work on BlackBerry and iOS. I haven't seen any events on Android yet but perhaps this is a config issue on our end.

Comment: Kindly let me know if this works on Android for you. Didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you  need to install the cord-ova plugin and even in the eclipse install it by typing Phone-gap install it.While creating project choose that latest cor-dova which you have installed.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite follow your answer. Do I need to write a plugin to call the Android/iOS Flurry SDKs or can I use the HTML5 flurry SDK and just call them from my javascript?